# How to display GPU utilization for iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad, gpu, diagnostics

I'm working on diagnostic tools for an iPad app, and I'd like to render both the CPU and GPU into a table view. I've successfully pulled the CPU, but can't find a hook to determine the GPU utilization/availability. Is there a method, similar to the sysctl library, in iOS?

Thanks.